# Using tryCatch to avoid erros in a double loop

Tags: r, try-catch

I have to write a double loop in order to check the right parameters for 'i' and 'j', so I thought I could use tryCatch() to keep the program running when parameters that do not fit a distribution are met.

I've written the following code:

```
tryCatch({
for (i in -2:2) {
  for (j in 0:6) {
    parms<-JohnsonFit(c(0, 1, i, j), moment="use")
    sJohnson(parms)
    datos <- rJohnson(1000, parms)
    plot(density(datos))
    }
  }
})
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in JohnsonFit(c(0, 1, i, j), moment = "use") :
```

Moment ratio in error

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the comment here for the use of trycatch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/16730940     In essence I think it is a mistake to wrap the outer loops in the trycatch - it should be (part of) the innermost layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```r
for (i in -2:2) {
  for (j in 0:6) {
    try({
      parms <- JohnsonFit(c(0, 1, i, j), moment="use")
      sJohnson(parms)
      datos <- rJohnson(1000, parms)
      plot(density(datos))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it could do the trick. But, why tryCatch() doesn't work? Is there a simple way to obtain the same results with instead of using try()?

Comment: @TraderInTheMaking With `tryCatch`, you have to include `error = function(e) {something}` otherwise the error is not caught.